# Show unread item count in Google Chrome extention icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

Is it possible to show unread item count in Google Chrome extension icon? If yes, then can someone point me to some pointers which explains how to do it?

I went through Google Chrome extension documentation, but couldn't figure it

Comment: Take a look at `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText`. http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the browser-action's **[badge](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#badge)**.

> ...a bit of text that is layered over the icon...

A badge has a background color and optionally some text and is used for displaying small bits of info (such as unread item count).

Use **[chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#method-setBadgeText)** to set/unset the text and **[chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#method-setBadgeBackgroundColor)** to set its color. E.g.:

```
var ba = chrome.browserAction;

function setAllRead() {
  ba.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: [0, 255, 0, 128]});
  ba.setBadgeText({text: ' '});   // <-- set text to '' to remove the badge
}

function setUnread(unreadItemCount) {
  ba.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: [255, 0, 0, 128]});
  ba.setBadgeText({text: '' + unreadItemCount});
}
```

Then use `setUnread()` and `setAllRead()` to show/hide the unread items count.

Comment: And how can I have a script running constantly to update this?

Comment: @minseong: It depends on your implementation (and how you can detect when it needs updating).

Comment: It's OK. I used alarms to fix it.

Comment: Aren't these identifier names a bit unfortunate? bs and cnt?